# How to delete a column of a csv by converting it to pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python and jupyter notebook.
I have a csv file that I would like to delete a column from. I am trying to read it as a pandas dataframe, delete a column of the pandas, and then turn that into a new csv.
I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
df.to_csv('Data.csv')
```

However, when I go to look at the new 'Data.csv', there is a new column 'Unnamed:0.1'. Is it adding a new column when I try to delete a column?

Comment: Probably `df.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)`. The default is to write the index and the unnamed index gets written without a header, so my guess is next time you read it, what was the index now becomes a new column and since it had no name is named `'Unnamed: 0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the '.to_csv' line as below

```py
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
df.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)
```

This will ensure that there won't be an extra column preserving index when the dataframe is saved.